# Set predefined date into input type

Tags: datepicker, momentjs, daterangepicker

[image]

I want to set predefined date range into datepicker.

When user click button then below date will be set into the input type.

startdate: 1 jan, 2017
enddate: 31 jan, 2017

```
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="daterangeperiod" name="daterangeperiod" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setRange`](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/#methods) method

> Sets the selected date range.

It accepts an object with `start` and end `key`. Both keys are JavaScript Date objects.

Here a working sample:

```js
$("#daterangeperiod").daterangepicker();
$("#daterangeperiod").daterangepicker("setRange", {
  start: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
  end:   new Date(2017, 0, 31)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tamble/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/0.5.0/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tamble/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/0.5.0/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="daterangeperiod" name="daterangeperiod" />
```

Comment: @RakeshTripathi glad to help. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you need help) if the answer solved your problem.